# Switch and checkbox setchecked function not working in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

```
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import okhttp3.FormBody;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    String token;

    Button on,on2;
    Button off,off2;
    TextView distance;
    DatabaseReference dref;
    String status;
    //FirebaseFirestore firestore;
    //Button btn3 ,btn4;
    TextView sens1,sens2,sens3,sens4;


    TextView tx2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        EditText tx=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        Switch control=findViewById(R.id.control1);
        CheckBox ch1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chk1);
        tx2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        sens1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.rsens1);
        sens2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.rsens2);
        sens3=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.rsens3);
        sens4=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.rsens4);

        System.out.println("SWITCH IS"+control);

        String app_server_url="url";



        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("LED_STATUS");
        dref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        dref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                status=dataSnapshot.child("sensor1").getValue().toString();
                sens1.setText(status);
                status=dataSnapshot.child("sensor2").getValue().toString();
                sens2.setText(status);
                status=dataSnapshot.child("sensor3").getValue().toString();
                sens3.setText(status);
                status=dataSnapshot.child("sensor4").getValue().toString();
                sens4.setText(status);
                status=dataSnapshot.child("control1").getValue().toString();
                if(Integer.parseInt(status)==1){
                    control.setChecked(true);
                }
                else{
                    control.setChecked(false);
                }


            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        control.setChecked(true);


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance ().getToken ().addOnCompleteListener (task -> {
                    Log.e("spalsh",task.getResult());
                    token=task.getResult();
                    System.out.println("tokenis"+token);
                    tx.setText("t");
                    setClipboard(getApplicationContext(),token);




                });
                StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, app_server_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                })
                {
                    @Nullable
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                        Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<String,String>();
                        params.put("fcm_token",token);
                        return params;

                    }
                };
            MySingleton.getmInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequest(stringRequest);

            }
        });


    }
```

this is my code i want to set the switch to true but it doesnt work, i want to read value from firebase and based on that i want to set switch to true or false
i also tried to  used setchecked and setselected on checkbox and switch and radiobutton but nothing work  , what im doing wrong ?

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:width="500px"
                android:text="sensor1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rsens1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:width="500px"
                android:text="rsens1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:width="500px"
                android:text="sensor2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rsens2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="rsens2" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="sensor3" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rsens3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="rsens3" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="sensor4" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rsens4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="rsens4" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chk1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="CheckBox" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/control1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="control1"
            tools:checked="false" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/control4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="control4" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/control3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="control3" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/control2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="control2" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is my activity_main.xml

Comment: Are you getting any warnings in compile time or any exceptions in runtime?

Comment: no im not getting any exceptions

Comment: Remove the second `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` line. That's basically replacing the `View`s assigned right before it with new instances, and the original ones are no longer on screen.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it wrong you cant use setchecked() on switch

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).